# Adding On Page Load jQuery Functionality

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery AJAX call (on Wordpress site) that works perfectly fine when selecting a value from the dropdown menu (on change). However, how do I also run this on page load?

My understanding is that I need to use `$( document ).ready()` however I'm getting stuck as to how this should be appended to the existing code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery('#teamsID').on( 'change', function () {
         valueSelect = $(this).val();
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'call_team_stats',
            value: valueSelect,
        },
         success:function(output){
             jQuery('#stats').html( output );
         }
     });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After defining the event handler, call `.change()` to trigger the event as if the user had selected something from the dropdown.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var valueCheck;
  jQuery('#teamsID').on('change', function() {
    valueSelect = $(this).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: {
        action: 'call_team_stats',
        value: valueSelect,
      },
      success: function(output) {
        jQuery('#stats').html(output);
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, this works great. Super simple yet I spent a long time on it. Appreciate your response